# Cocos2d and usage of CCAnimationCache

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, memcached

I'd like to understand the usage of CCAnimationCache.

I have a cache of enemies objects. Each object has two CCAnimations member variables, a standard animation and a special animation. The frames in the animation varies according to the type property of the enemy object.

```
@interface EnemyEntity : Entity
{
    EnemyTypes type;
    CCAnimation * animation;
    CCAnimationCache * animationCache;
}
```

As it is often the case that in the screen I do have several instances of the same enemy type I am wondering if I should use a CCAnimationCache instead a CCAnimation member variable.

And if so where should I put the CCAnimationCache instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh. Don't you read comments in headers?

```
/** Singleton that manages the Animations.
 It saves in a cache the animations. You should use this class if you want to save your animations in a cache.

 Before v0.99.5, the recommend way was to save them on the CCSprite. Since v0.99.5, you should use this class instead.

 @since v0.99.5
 */
```

This comment is in the `CCAnimationCache.h` file. So, this is a cocos2d singleton as others (CCTextureCache, CCSpriteFrameCache). If you want to use it, just call

```
CCAnimationCache* animationCache = [CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache];
```

Comment: Oh man, I had read it but did not realize that was a singleton. Wow! That's much easier than I thought :). Thanks!